# IBM Cloud Private - Stopped container restarts automatically

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

In IBM Cloud Private when stopping a Docker container, it automatically restarts.  How can it be stopped?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit more information:

- When you work with containers on IBM Cloud Private, you'd actually deploying individual Pods or more likely Deployments.
- When a Pod is managed by a ReplicaSet, DaemonSet, or StatefulSet, there are semantics which apply to reschedule the pod if it fails unexpectedly. Deleting a Pod isn't distinguished from other failures within a pod (application crashes or worker node failure).

You should be using `kubectl` to work with pods. You can configure `kubectl` from User > Configure Client in the top right corner of the web UI. Copy and paste the commands for your environment into your console. Validate that the IP or network address is resolvable from your client machine (control this value in the install `cluster/config.yaml` with `cluster_access_ip`).

Example `kubectl` configure steps (Copy from User > Configure Client in the web UI):

```
kubectl config set-cluster mycluster.icp --server=https://[NETWORK_ADDRESS]:8001 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
kubectl config set-context mycluster.icp-context --cluster=mycluster.icp
kubectl config set-credentials mycluster.icp-user --token=[TOKEN]
kubectl config set-context mycluster.icp-context --user=mycluster.icp-user --namespace=default
kubectl config use-context mycluster.icp-context
```

Then view running pods:

```
kubectl get pods [--namespace default]
```

These pods represent the basic unit of deployment: containers + volumes + labels + links to ConfigMaps and Secrets.

These pods are generally deployed from other management "sets":

```
kubectl get deployments [--namespace default] 
kubectl get daemonsets [--namespace default] 
kubectl get statefulsets [--namespace default]
```

These collections represent policy + pods; behaviors about how to recover are built into each construct.

You probably have a deployment, so to remove the container --

```
kubectl get deployments -o wide [--namespace default]
```

Find the deployment of interest, and delete it:

```
kubectl delete deployments my-deployment [--namespace default]
```

Now the `deployment` will be removed, along with all associated pods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the kubelet first, otherwise it will automatically start up exited containers.  You can run “systemctl stop kubelet”.

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes restarts failed containers (pods), you should scale the deployment to 0 instances or delete the deployment, both can be achieved with kubectl (kubectl scale --replicas=0 ...) or using ICP console.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the number of replicas to zero.